# pass more than 1 variables from the url for a multi language website

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am doing a multi language website for which i use a route:group with a prefix in my route.php.

Now, i am trying to grab the variables of language to know which language i am viewing the website, and then use it to query database.

I have found a problem, how to get more than 1 variables from the url?

```
Route::get('/{vedi}/{fuffa}', function($vedi, $fuffa)
{

    $arrays=array(['campo'=>$vedi,
            'lingua'=>$fuffa]);

    return View::make('abc')->with('data',$arrays);
    });
```

then in my 'abc' view i would ask for a

```
{{$data->campo}}
```

but he tell me it's not a n object.
1) how can i do?
2)is this a corret approach to build a website multilanguage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) 
You are trying to access your data via a `$data` object that does not exist. You try to access your values like if `$data` was an object (by using `->campo`).

What actually happens that you have an array. In your case, you can access your variables like this:

```
{{ $data['campo'] }}
```

What you also can do:

```
$arrays=array('campo'=>$vedi,
    'lingua'=>$fuffa);

return View::make('abc')->with($arrays);
});
```

And then, in your view, you will have the variables directly available, without being in one $data array:

```
{{ $campo }}
```

For 2)
You can make use of laravels Localization functionality. Basically, you make one or many files for each language where you have the same structure of messages. In your views, you acceess the same messages, but based on the viewers chosen language the correct message is shown.

[See Laravel Localization here](http://laravel.com/docs/localization)

Comment: thank you for the answer.
1) i actually have some confunsion about object and array. Why i can't store my data in an object? 
2)i don't need to use array([..=>.. , ..=>..]) it's ok even withouth []
3)wha change from the 1st and the second method u told me?
3) for the purpose of writing a description for each database products (that can also be inserted) is useless localization right?

Comment: You can store your data in an object, but then you have to create a class first. Objects are instantiations of classes. You don't want to do that for pure data storage, arrays are much more convenient. 2) The [] brackets are used to access an array. If you have $data = array('name' => 'paul'); you can access the name via $data['name'].  I do not fully understand what you want to ask with your 3rd question

Comment: i have multiple description of my product in english, italian, french, and so on. If this can't be inserted i would be fine with localization functionality right?
But if i allow user to insert a product, i can't use localization things?